# Using Office Word to read doc files with PHP

Tags: php, ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to use PHP with `word.application` to read a file. It simply will not open the file.  It's echoing the right version.

```
$w = new COM("word.application") or die("Is office installed?");
echo 'Loaded Word, version ' . $w->Version . '<br>'; 
$w->Visible = false;

$w->Documents->Open(realpath('test.docx'));

$content = (string) $w->ActiveDocument->Content;

echo $content;

$w->Quit();
$w->Release();
$w = null;
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Source: Microsoft Word
Description: This command is not available because no document is open.'
```

It feels like it's some kind of permission problem. I tried to put the path of the `test.docx` besides using realpath and that did not help. Also tried to put it in the root of my C drive. I am using Windows 7 Professional and Microsoft Office 2007.

Comment: are you sure the path to the file is correct? Try to specify an absolute path.

Comment: I have triple checked the path even with an absolute path, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Documents->Open returns a document if all is ok. Probably, the document does not exists (path incorrect), or you haven't got the rights to open it from PHP. Store the result in $var, check if it has an appropriate value (probably `not isset`, `null` or `false` if not), and use $var->Content to read the content.

Comment: When I store it in a $var and echo the $var. The result is null.

Comment: That conforms the assumption that the document cannot be opened. You will need to find out why. Maybe you could try other file functions in PHP to check if the file can be found at all and if you have the permissions needed to open the file. Merely seeing that the file exists doesn't guarantee that you can open it as well. Try to put the document in another location, like your document root folder.

Comment: I have tried that and tried other documents. Also made documents just to try. I was able to convert it using Open Office via command line but I would like to get this to work.

Comment: If you call `$w->Documents->Add();` do you get an object then? It will not have any content, but at least you will know if you can at all add documents to your documents collection. Also, have you tried to read the file using file_get_contents? Did you see any data (garbage, probably)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try doing a file_exists on said
   file/path.
2. If that works, try
   file_get_contents and see if you can
   read it.

If that all works - then it's not a problem with permissions/etc.