# how to put condition for uploading only word files

Tags: php, file, upload, ms-word

```
if(isset($_POST["upload"]))
{
    if( ($_FILES['file']['name']!='') && ($_FILES['file']['type']=="   image/png") )
    {
        $filepath=rand(1111,9999).$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'quotations/'.$filepath);
    }
}
```

This is my code for uplaoding an image of format PNG. Now instead of PNG I want that it should upload only Word files. How do I write the condition for uploading only Word files?

Comment: Do you want to stop them before they start the upload or after the file has already been uploaded to your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<input type="file" accept=".doc">`

or

```
$filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
if ($ext == ".doc"){
   //Do your code for uploading here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build an array of allowed file types, something like this:

```
$onlyAllow = array();
$onlyAllow[] = 'image/png';
$onlyAllow[] = 'application/msword'
$onlyAllow[] = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';   //Word .docx
```

You can then test against that array using `in_array`

```
if(isset($_POST["upload"])) {
    if( ($_FILES['file']['name']!='') && in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], $onlyAllow)) {
        $filepath=rand(1111,9999).$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'quotations/'.$filepath);
    }
}
```

When you need to add a new allowed file just add it to your array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just looking at the extension, you could get more restrictive by looking at the MIME type. There are numerous posts here at Stackoverflow concerning this problem. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659936/using-office-word-to-read-doc-files-with-php) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807036/php-5-3-5-fileinfo-mime-type-for-ms-office-2007-files-magic-mime-updates).

Especially the last one provides some useful info regarding newer versions of Office. In here, the documents are actually compressed zip files, which means that the MIME type is incorrectly identified as ZIP.